# Enable cipher suite TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Tags: windows-10, powershell, ssl

I need to connect to an *old* device, which doesn't support any modern cipher suites, currently, I get the error:

```
iwr : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

nmap's ssl script shows it allowing only these:

```
TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA - F
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA - F
```

But these don't seem to match up with any of the ciphers I can enable using powershell:

```
Get-TlsCipherSuite|%{$_.name}

Name                                   
----                                   
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384  
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256  
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA     
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA     
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA   
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA   
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384        
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256        
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256        
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256        
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA           
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

Am I missing ciphers? I wouldn't be too surprised if windows 10 had removed some ancient ones. I couldn't find any information about which ciphers should be available in different versions, or what the `DH_anon` resolve to in windows to be able to enable it.

Comment: `*anon*` ciphers are not supported by modern TLS clients by default and where never supported by default. These ciphers don't provide any actual protection since it can not be checked that the server is actually the correct one (no authentication of the server done). This means there would have been special clients to access such device in the first place.

Comment: As far as I know .Net uses the default Schannel SSL/TLS library from Windows which can only be configured globally (don't know if the anon ciphers are still included). Therefore my advice would be to use a "proxy" executable that uses an integrated SSL library. E.g. search for older socat.exe with SSL support, then you could start it and connect to it on localhost via TCP and socat forwards the data via SSL to the device.

Comment: I don't mind configuring it globally (I need to pull a ton of data off of it before retiring the device, so I can set it back after I'm done). It looks like socat is reasonable if used with old openssl. I just need https traffic, so I like the idea of a proxy